# Converting recursive equation into matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recursive-algorithms

Here is example of converting fibonacci function into matrices.

Fibonacci sequence defines

$$
f(1)=1
$$

$$
f(2)=1
$$

$$
f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2)
$$

It can be converted into matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix}
f(n+1) & f(n) \\
f(n) & f(n-1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For example. if we want to find the 400th fibonacci number, then we do this calculation.
$$
A_{1}= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{400}
$$

I have similar problem. I'd like to know if this problem can be converted into matrix or not.
It is the problem description.

Suppose, we have a table

Table 1. Table of $F_i$ and $A_i$

| i | $F_i$ | $A_i$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 0 | 0.45 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.55 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.92 |

Table 2. Table of set $S_i$

| i | $S_i$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {0, 2} |
| 1 | {1, 3} |

The equation is written below.

$$
f(i, 1) = A_i
$$

$$
f(i, d) = A_i + g(F_i, d - 1) 
$$

$$
g(i, d) = \sum_{j}^{j \in S_i} f(j, d)
$$

I'd like to calculate $f(0, 400)$ using matrix. Could you tell me if this problem can be converted into matrix, please?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What exactly is this sum defining $g(i,d)$? Could you calculate explicity some terms of yours sequence?

Comment: In this case, $g(0,d)=f(0,d)+f(2,d)$ and $g(1,d)=f(1,d)+f(3,d)$. In other word, $g(i,d)$ is sum of $f(j,d)$ for each $j$ which is element of set $S_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Your system can be write as
$$X(d)=MX(d-1)+A$$
where
$$X(d)=\begin{bmatrix}
f(0,d)\\
f(1,d) \\
f(2,d) \\
f(3,d) 
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$
and
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_0\\
A_1 \\
A_2 \\
A_3 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
With initial condition $X(1)=A$. By noting that the matriz $M$ satisfies $M^n=2^{n-2}U$ where
$$U=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$
we have
$$X(d)=M^{d-1}A+...+M^3A+M^2A+MA+A$$
that is
$$X(d)=2^{d-3}UA+...+2^2UA+2^1UA+2^0UA+MA+A$$
$$X(d)=(2^{d-3}+...+2^2+2^1+2^0)UA+MA+A$$
$$X(d)=(2^{d-2}-1)UA+MA+A.$$

It's interest to note that, although the dynamics occur in $R^4$, the essential behavior is in a 2d plane.